# How can I find the eigenvalues of $\alpha$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

The question is given below:

> [image]

**My trial is:**
Let $\lambda $ be an eigenvalue of $\alpha,$ then 
 $$ \alpha (
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a \\
   b \\
   c \\
   d \\
  \end{array} } \right] 
) = \lambda
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a \\
   b \\
   c \\
   d \\
  \end{array} } \right]
 = 
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \lambda a \\
   \lambda b \\
   \lambda c \\
   \lambda d
  \end{array} } \right]
 $$

$$i.e. \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   b + c \\
   c \\
   0 \\
   0 \\
  \end{array} } \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \lambda a \\
   \lambda b \\
   \lambda c \\
   \lambda d
  \end{array} } \right]
 \rightarrow (1.)$$

Now, for $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a \\
   b \\
   c \\
   d \\
  \end{array} } \right] $ to be an eigenvector, at least one of $a, b, c, d$ must be nonzero. WLOG, let $a \neq 0.$ Therefore from $(1.)$ we have $$\lambda = \frac {b + c}{a}, \lambda b = c \quad i.e. \quad  b^2 = c(a-b), \lambda c = 0 \quad  i.e. c^2 = (-bc).$$ but then what?

Could anyone help me in solving this, please?

Comment: Did you try to solve with characteristic polynomial?

Comment: No, I do not know what is the matrix corresponding to $\alpha$@MatheusNunes could you please tell me how can I find it?

Comment: what basis should I choose to find  the matrix corresponding to this linear transformation?@MatheusNunes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From (1.), we have $\lambda c=0$ and $\lambda d=0$, so $\lambda=0$ is one solution.

Otherwise, $c=0$ and $d=0$, and $c=\lambda b$, so $\lambda=0$ or $b=0$.

But if $c=d=b=0$, then $\lambda a=b+c=0$, so $a=0$ too, so there are no eigenvalues besides $\lambda=0$.

Comment: Here's a [check](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues+of+%7B%7B0%2C1%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%7D)

Comment: what basis should I choose for the matrix corresponding to this linear transformation?

Comment: I used the standard basis in the check above

Comment: Any basis should suffice since the choice of basis does not affect the eigenvalues of  the linear transformation. ( Although picking the standard basis is much easier and straightforward. )

Comment: how are the generalized eigenvectors calculated?

Answer (score 2):

**Another way to do:**

$$\alpha(a,b,c,d)=(b+c,c,0,0).$$

Assuming that $e_1,\dots, e_4$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Then,

$$\alpha(e_1)=(0,0,0,0)$$
$$\alpha(e_2)=(1,0,0,0)$$
$$\alpha(e_3)=(1,1,0,0)$$
$$\alpha(e_4)=(0,0,0,0)$$

The matrix associated to $\alpha$ is:

$$[\alpha]=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then, the charascterisc polynomail of $[\alpha]$ is

$$p(\lambda)= \det(\lambda I - [\alpha])= \det\left[\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda 
\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\right] = \det\left[\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & -1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda 
\end{pmatrix}\right]$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: I will try and tell you what I did :) thanks

Comment: I proceeded and the only eigenvalue was zero thanks for helping me :)